# Extract only value in key value pair in $project in mongodb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongo 3.4

I'm using the aggregate function of mongodb. My issue is that in $project I'm having a value as

```
{ $project: {
  "_id": 1,
  "name":1 ,
  ............
  ............
  "partners.address.country": 1,
  "partners.partnerName": 1,
} },
{ $match: matchCondition
}
```

In result , I'm getting value as

> "partners" : {"address" : {"country" : " "}}

I don't want that  I simply want it as

> "partners" : {"country" : " "}

I want to skip address part. Also, I don't want to use `.map` function after the result as I have large data in **$project**.
Can anybody help?

I have one more query 
this query is a join of 4 collections (2 others which I hadn't mention the above example). I want the whole record of my main collection & only 2-3 records of others collections, so, I have to write each & every record in $project and set it as 1.
Is there a way through which we can skip to write each & every record in $project and still we can get the record in our result?
Please help me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: my answer explains about your first question but your second question is bit unclear & you need to provide some sample data after joining all collections & required o/p to understand it easy, If it's becoming large enough I would say to raise a new question to make it look clear !! So in general if you use `$lookup` to join 4 collections each of the join data will be under a respective field which is an array of docs from respective collections, You can use `$addFields` to add new fields to document - So **$splice** the arrays & add respective fields to main doc !!

Comment: I want to include all the fields of the primary collection but the issue is that I have to write all the fields in $project & assign it to 1.
But, I want something dynamic like without writing name of each field of main  collection, I want all of them.

Comment: In MongoDB you've two options to transform fields in docs `$project` or `$addFields`, So you can look into `$addFields` of MongoDB here :: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try as like below :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    name: 1,
    "partners.country": "$partners.address.country", // a new field(country) will be created & a value will be assigned from given field
    "partners.partnerName": 1
  }
})
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FU__YQMubDk)

Comment: It worked.
But if suppose, we have an address as null then will it generate an error?

Comment: @SHIVAMSHARMA : MongoDB should ignore that case !! You can try it in playground..